# Update query not executed

Tags: mongoose

I'm trying to achieve a simple update but no query is issued to MongoDB, and mongoose doesn't generate any debugging message for this one. My callback is being executed though, returning 'null 0 undefined'. If I force the execution adding a call to 'exec()' after the update method, my query gets translated into a find. What am I missing?

```
mongoose.set('debug', true);

var where = {fullname : 'Nitro Recycled Titleist Nxt Golf Balls'};
var setValues = {pubblished : true};

Ball.where(where).setOptions({ multi: false }).update({ $set: setValues}, function(err, numberAffected, raw) {
    console.log(err, numberAffected, raw);
    if (err) {
        return res.send(400, {message: getErrorMessage(err)});
    } else {
        return res.send(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Should it be `published` instead of `pubblished`?

Comment: you're right, although it should get executed anyway

Comment: No, Mongoose will see that `pubblished` is not in your schema and find nothing to apply the `update` to so it will just skip it.

Comment: Ah! Didn't think there was such a check when creating my own query. Thanks a ton!